# Should C++/CLI data members be handles or values?

Tags: c++-cli

I'm new to C++/CLI and I'm wondering what is "best practice" regarding managed type data members. Declaring as handle:

```
public ref class A {
public:
    A() : myList(gcnew List<int>()) {}
private:
    List<int>^ myList;
};
```

or as a value:

```
public ref class B {
private:
    List<int> myList;
};
```

Can't seem to find definitive advice on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing managed C++ code, I'm in favor of following the conventions used by the other managed languages. Therefore, I'd go with handles for class-level data members, and only use values (stack semantics) where you'd use a `using` statement in C#.

If your class member is a value, then replacing the object entirely means that the object would need a copy constructor defined, and not many .NET classes do. Also, if you want to pass the object to another method, you'll need to use the `%` operator to convert from `List<int>` to `List<int>^`. (Not a big deal to type `%`, but easy to forget, and the compiler error just says it can't convert `List<int>` to `List<int>^`.)

```
//Example of the `%` operator
void CSharpMethodThatDoesSomethingWithAList(List<int>^ list) { }

List<int> valueList;
CSharpMethodThatDoesSomethingWithAList(%valueList);

List<int>^ handleList = gcnew List<int>();
CSharpMethodThatDoesSomethingWithAList(handleList);
```

Comment: This makes sense because it makes using .NET feel more natural since the parameters are usually handles.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would use the second form. I say this because I use frameworks that are written by other teams of people, and they use this form.

I believe this is because it is cleaner, uses less space, and is easier for the non-author to read. I try to keep in mind that the most concise code, while still being readable by someone with minimal knowledge of the project is best.

Also, I have not encountered any problems with the latter example in terms of readability across header files, methods, classes, or data files ...etc

Though I'm **FAR** from an expert in the matter, that is what I prefer. Makes more sense to me.

```
class AlgoCompSelector : public TSelector {
   public :
   AlgoCompSelector( TTree *tree = 0 );
   virtual ~AlgoCompSelector(){ /* */ };
   virtual void    Init(TTree *tree);
   virtual void    SlaveBegin(TTree *tree);
   virtual Bool_t  Process(Long64_t entry);
   virtual void    Terminate();
   virtual Int_t   Version() const { return 1; }

   void setAlgo( Int_t idx, const Char_t *name, TTree* part2, TTree* part3 );
   void setPTthres( Float_t val );
   void setEthres( Float_t val );                                                                                                                   

   private:
   std::string mAlgoName[2];                  // use this for the axis labels and/or          legend labels.                                         
   TTree *mPart1;
   TTree *mPart2[2], *mPart3[2];     // pointers to TTrees of the various parts                                                              
   TBranch *mPhotonBranch[2];                 // Used branches                                                                               
   TClonesArray *mPhotonArray[2];             // To point to the array in the tree
```

for example

Comment: Are you sure it takes less space for managed typed? It is not possible to inline a managed class into another one on the CLR level.

Comment: when I say space, I mean literally, space, not memory. I like concise code, which **usually** means less memory space as well.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the lifetime.  When you have a private member which lives exactly as long as the owning class, the second form is preferable.